# The downside of using a preview release framework

Tags: symfony, php

I'm thining about using symfony 2.0 for my new project. It's only preview a release at the moment, the final release is due in March which is around the same time I expect my project to go live.

Are there any reasons why I shoulnd't be using 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasons? Yes you shouldn't use it because Sensio who "make" Symfony tell you not to.

Even though it close to thier slated march release they could still make wholesale changes to the api which would leave you stranded and with a lot of rewriting on your hands. 1.4 is very stable and well documented and will be supported until at least 2012 and so unless there is something in the S2 technology that you cannot deliver you project without then stick with 1.4.

I was in two minds myself as i am developing app that will not get release until April or later and so was tempted. My plan is to build the apps in 1.4 but to build stripped down skeletons that match the 1.4 builds to see how they perform and to then build into later in 2011 when 2.0 has notched up a few revision numbers, and stabilised, and got a better body of documentation behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Symfony2 is really lacking at the moment, and seeing as it's so very different from symfony 1.4 (well of course, it's a total rewrite) it's rather hard to just pick up and use in its current state.

I'd say use 1.4 for now, and when the documentation picks up, give 2.0 a try. 2.0 does look exciting though, I can understand the temptation!